# Restoring const-correctness for NN forward pass

Tags: libtorch

I am trying to implement a simple neural network using pytorch/libtorch. The following example is adapted from the [libtorch cpp frontend tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/advanced/cpp_frontend.html#the-generator-module).

```
#include <torch/torch.h>
struct DeepQImpl : torch::nn::Module {
    DeepQImpl(size_t N)
        : linear1(2,5),
          linear2(5,3) {}
    torch::Tensor forward(torch::Tensor x) const {
        x = torch::tanh(linear1(x));
        x = linear2(x);
        return x;
    }
    torch::nn::Linear linear1, linear2;
};
TORCH_MODULE(DeepQ);
```

Note that the function `forward` is declared `const`. The code I am writing requires the evalutation of the NN to be a const function, which seems reasonable to me.
This code does not compile though. The compiler throws

> error: no match for call to ‘(const torch::nn::Linear) (at::Tensor&)’
>   x = linear1(x);

I have found a way around this though, by defining the layers to be `mutable`:

```
#include <torch/torch.h>
struct DeepQImpl : torch::nn::Module {
    /* all the code */
    mutable torch::nn:Linear linear1, linear2;
};
```

So my question is

1. Why is the application of a layer on a tensor not `const`
2. Is using `mutable` the way to fix this and is it safe?

My intuition is that in the forward pass, the layers get assembled into a structure that can be used for the back-propagation, requiring some writing operation. If that's true, the question becomes how to assemble the layers in a first (non-`const`) step and then evaluate the structure in a second (`const`) step.

Comment: why do you need a `const forward` function? Do you want to have a `const` non-changeable trained network just for inference?

Comment: As you guessed, you cannot use `const` in the declaration of the `forward` since it means that you do not allow any change of values of any type in the `forward` function. Though, it is not correct since `forward` function builds a graph sequence to create the forward and backward passes over the network.

Comment: I an algorithm that uses a regression model. I want to 'drop-in' different regression models, (e.g. simple linear vs Neural Network). The way the algorithm is written right now requires the evaluation to be `const`. If I can't evaluate the NN as `const`, I have to remove the modifier in my other regression models as well, so that they can be used via the same interface.

Comment: If you want just a forward pass over a trained model, you can easily pass the whole `const DeepQ &instance_name` in the input of a function to evaluate, not just passing the `forward` function. I have tried this and it works.